# How to check out merge request branch in GitLab coming from fork you don't have access to?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, merge-request

I'm trying to learn about merge requests and in particular how those work in GitLab.

Given a project `MAIN` by user `USER_MAIN` (role: Maintainer) another user `USER_OTHER` has been invited to join (role: Developer). `USER_OTHER` creates a fork `FORK` of `MAIN`. The repository `FORK` belongs to `USER_OTHER` and `USER_MAIN` has no access to it.

`USER_OTHER` commits changes to a specific branch in `FORK` and makes a merge request. Now `USER_MAIN` needs to see if the changes are correct.

And here is where I'm stuck. In the **Merge request** section of `MAIN` I get this:

[image: Merge request in GitLab]

I would like to checkout the branch locally. For that I clicked on **Check out branch** and got this:

[image: Check out branch in merge request]

I tried fetching it but I get

> remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
> fatal: repository 'https://XXXX/USER_OTHER/FORK.git' not found

And indeed since I'm not a member of `FORK` I cannot even see the repository.

How would I deal with this? I know that merge requests are not actually part of **git** but were rather introduced at a later stage (I think by GitHub) so I'm thinking perhaps I can complete the merge request only via the Web UI (or perhaps the GitLab API, which I don't want to deal with right now).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to contact your external contributor, and request access to  their fork.

That would allow you to complete the recommended GitLab steps.

Comment: I can merge even now. It's just that right now I'm forced to do that only via the Web UI. I can still view the changes and commits using the WebIDE.